# Потоки. Ожидание выполнения потоков с++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mutex

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить 1ю и 2ю функцию выполняться одновременно, а третью ждать пока они обе выполняться? Заранее спасибо. Вот код, но на третье

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread> 
#include <string>
#include <vector> 
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
mutex g_lock;
mutex c_lock;

void anyFunc1(mutex& mtx) {
    mtx.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sleep(400);
        cout << "1 \n";
    }
}
void anyFunc2(mutex& mtx) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sleep(400);
        cout << "2 \n";
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}
void anyFunc3(mutex& mtx) {
    mtx.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Sleep(400);
        cout << "3 \n";
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}

int main() {
    mutex mtx;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    thread func_thread1(anyFunc1, ref(mtx));
    thread func_thread2(anyFunc2, ref(mtx));
    thread func_thread3(anyFunc3, ref(mtx));
    func_thread1.join();
    func_thread2.join();
    func_thread3.join();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ожидание выполнения потока делается через join. Мьютекс для этой задачи не нужен. Как и лишние два потока.

```
thread func_thread1(anyFunc1);
anyFunc2();
func_thread1.join();
anyFunc3();
```